# How to view which apps are using the most RAM?

Tags: applications, ram

I recently bought a [Samsung Galaxy M52 5G](https://gadgets360.com/mobiles/news/samsung-m52-5g-launch-expected-soon-us-fcc-bluetooth-sig-specifications-model-number-sm-526b-ds-sm-526br-ds-galaxy-2531555). Now for the past few days, it has been slow/erratic even though I don't have that many apps. The most troubling is that Android reports my RAM usage is high even though there are no background apps, or at least that should be the case when I just rebooted the phone.

Is there any way to tell which apps are taking most of the memory?

Comment: See "Running services" or "Memory"  section in "Developer options". If you want an app, see [How to view RAM and swap usage on Android?](https://mirfatif.github.io/IAnswers/ram_swap_usage_android.htm). I'm the author of the app: [WhatsRunning](https://github.com/mirfatif/WhatsRunning).